# Regex expression to find all occurences of 'NSLocalizedString' in file contents

Tags: python, regex, string-parsing, nslocalizedstring

Test cases:

```
// With text and comment
NSLocalizedString(@"Example Text", @"Example Comment");

// With text and no comment
NSLocalizedString(@"Example, text", nil) 

// With text and comment with paranthesis
NSLocalizedString(@"Example text", @"Example (with paranthesis) comment") 

// With property and no comment
NSLocalizedString(test, nil)

// With property and comment
NSLocalizedString(test, @"Example comment")

// Inline
NSLocalizedString(@"Error", nil) NSLocalizedString(@"Change settings", @"Option to change HTTP Post settings") NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", nil)
```

What I'm looking for: one match per `NSLocalizedString` occurance, with two capture groups (key and comment). Key may have a value or be `nil`.

What I've tried: `r'NSLocalizedString\((.*)\s*,\s*(.*)\)'`

This works for most of the cases, except for the last one (Inline) because it matches at the last comma.

Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/4OJgU2/6

Comment: I don't think it is possible to capture the arguments inside, but what you may use to match all the substrings will look like [this](https://regex101.com/r/WDTpRO/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This is a great start, thank you! Why wouldn’t it be possible to capture the elements inside?

Comment: Bcause they are all part of a [repeated capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html). You may do it in 2 steps: 1) https://regex101.com/r/WDTpRO/2 - capture them into Group 1, 2) re-parse (re-match) with https://regex101.com/r/WDTpRO/3.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew And can that be avoided? Or have other small capturing groups inside that match the key and comment... It's not a hard requirement to have only two capturing groups.

Comment: Well, in Python, you can even use PyPi regex module that lets you access all captures in a group. Can you use PyPi regex module?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, i can use PyPi regex (or any other package that fits the job)

Comment: See https://rextester.com/MXGEMW93632

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This is great! Any Idea how to use this with the regex.sub function? I'm trying to replace all occurrences of `NSLocalizedString({key}, {comment})` in a source code file, with `NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"elementID", nil, [NSBundle mainBundle], \1, \2)`, where `\1` and `\2` are the key and the comment groups

Comment: So, there can only be two arguments inside each `NSLocalizedString`? Then it is possible.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, only key and comment

Comment: See https://rextester.com/JQOUZE62997

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This is so awesome, thanks a lot! Please post it as an answer so I can accept it. Thank you again for your time!

Comment: Ok, so you do not even need the PyPi regex module :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187309/discussion-between-rhcpfan-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may solve the problem using

```
r'(?s)NSLocalizedString\(\s*(@\"[^\"\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\]*)*\"|\w+)\s*,\s*(@\"[^\"\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\]*)*\"|\w+)\)'
```

and the replacement

```
r'NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"elementID", nil, [NSBundle mainBundle], \1, \2)'
```

**Details**

- `NSLocalizedString\(` - `NSLocalizedString(` substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(@\"[^\"\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\]*)*\"|\w+)` - Group 1:

  - `@\"[^\"\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\]*)*\"` - `@"` followed with 0+ chars  other than `"` and `\` followed with 0+ repetitions of any escaped char followed with 0+ chars  other than `"` and `\` and then a `"` (it is the Obj-C string literal matching pattern)
  - `|` - or
  - `\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `\s*,\s*` - `,` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(@\"[^\"\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\]*)*\"|\w+)` - Group 2
- `\)` - a `)` char.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/YGuGtF):

```
import re
strs = ['NSLocalizedString(@"Example Text", @"Example Comment");', 'NSLocalizedString(@"Example, text", nil)', 'NSLocalizedString(@"Example text", @"Example (with paranthesis) comment")', 'NSLocalizedString(test, nil)', 'NSLocalizedString(test, @"Example comment")', 'NSLocalizedString(@"Error", nil) NSLocalizedString(@"Change settings", @"Option to change HTTP Post settings") NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", nil)']
pat = re.compile(r'NSLocalizedString\(\s*(@\"[^\"\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\]*)*\"|\w+)\s*,\s*(@\"[^\"\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\]*)*\"|\w+)\)', re.DOTALL)
repl = r'NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"elementID", nil, [NSBundle mainBundle], \1, \2)'
for s in strs:
    print('----------------------------------\n{}\nVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV'.format(s))
    res = pat.sub(repl, s)
    print(res)
```

Output:

```
----------------------------------
NSLocalizedString(@"Example Text", @"Example Comment");
VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"elementID", nil, [NSBundle mainBundle], @"Example Text", @"Example Comment");
----------------------------------
NSLocalizedString(@"Example, text", nil)
VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"elementID", nil, [NSBundle mainBundle], @"Example, text", nil)
----------------------------------
NSLocalizedString(@"Example text", @"Example (with paranthesis) comment")
VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"elementID", nil, [NSBundle mainBundle], @"Example text", @"Example (with paranthesis) comment")
----------------------------------
NSLocalizedString(test, nil)
VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"elementID", nil, [NSBundle mainBundle], test, nil)
----------------------------------
NSLocalizedString(test, @"Example comment")
VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"elementID", nil, [NSBundle mainBundle], test, @"Example comment")
----------------------------------
NSLocalizedString(@"Error", nil) NSLocalizedString(@"Change settings", @"Option to change HTTP Post settings") NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", nil)
VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"elementID", nil, [NSBundle mainBundle], @"Error", nil) NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"elementID", nil, [NSBundle mainBundle], @"Change settings", @"Option to change HTTP Post settings") NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"elementID", nil, [NSBundle mainBundle], @"Cancel", nil)
```